# Advance bundle js : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, checkout-page, jsbundling

i have implemented advance bundle js in magento2 all good but when i go to checkout page and change country no shipping method change.

then i debug the issue the issue comes when we enable bundling then i open my require config js file and debug the code ***bundles/checkout*** when i remove it complete then its working.

then i keep to js in bundle checkout if i remove ***Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-loader*** its working but when i put it then not works there are more than 25 js which creating problem what should i do now.

```
 require.config({
           bundles: {"bundles/checkout":[
       "Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-loader",
       "Magento_Paypal/js/view/payment/paypal-payments"
  });
```